# How to make openSUSE installer see my boot partition?

Tags: boot, system-installation, opensuse, partition-table

I would like to install openSUSE Leap 15.0 next to my old openSUSE (dual boot). But I am stuck at the partitioning stage. I have such partitions:

```
old (unused here)  /dev/sda1 (1GB) EFI System Partition Ext4
old (unused here)  /dev/sda2 LVM
intended as shared /dev/sda3 LVM
new                /dev/sda4 Linux Ext3 /
intended as shared /dev/sda5 LVM
new                /dev/sda6 (1GB) EFI System Partition Ext4 /boot
```

`/dev/sda1` is boot partition for and old system, I want to have `/dev/sda6` as boot for new system in order not to mess up the old setup. I would like to boot from new setup into old one instead to boot old setup and from there start the new one.

Anyway, boot partition is present, it is 1GB and yet no matter what I selected as format or id for this partition I constantly see warning "Missing device with size equal or bigger than 2 MiB and partition id bios_boot".

I switched of course from EFI SP to "Bios Boot Partition", the warning remains exactly the same.

*Just out of curiosity I deleted `/dev/sda6` and mounted the old `/dev/sda1` as `/boot` with formatting. Same warning.*

Comment: I see no partition of type bios_boot in the listing above. Which program did you use to produce the listing?

Comment: @JohanMyréen, I retyped from the screen what I saw (in openSUSE installer/partitioner). I wrote below that I switched `/dev/sda6` to BBP but the warning didn't go away. I also switched mount points, etc. and I selected `/dev/sda1` as `/boot` (after deleting `/dev/sda6`). All those thing didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

You were trying to create two EFI System Partitions, aka ESPs, **NOT** two /boot partitions.

You can only have one of those.

It should be safe to point your installer to the existing ESP, and add an entry to grub to boot both OSes from the grub in your Leap 15 installation, using something like what this guy did:

https://www.garron.me/en/linux/os-prober-update-grub-arch-linux-debian-ubuntu.html

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote before the listing shows one of my many tries. Another was having `/dev/sda6` as Bios Boot Partition mounted as `/boot` -- isn't this a boot partition?

Comment: The Grub BIOS boot partition should not be mounted. It should be a raw partition; it should not contain a file system. The purpose of the BIOS boot partition is to provide space on the disk for Grub code and data. On an MBR partitioned disk, Grub uses sectors after the boot record that are usually free, but with GPT this is normally not the case.